# How to click a javascripted' radio button and fetch next page using Python (urllib2)? [WebScrape, selenium]

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, screen-scraping

I am struggling with this. I have a fully tested python script. I have to make a small change wherein I have to first click on a radio button which in turn automatically executes a javascript function forwarding the page to a search form.

My working platform : Linux

Language : Python

Radio button code :

```
<input type="radio" language="javascript" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'_ctl0$Main$SearchRadio\',\'\')', 0)" value="SearchRadio" name="_ctl0:Main:SearchRadio" id="_ctl0_Main_SearchRadio">
```

Javascript code on the page :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
  if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
  function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
  // -->
</script>
```

This is what selenium does. Not sure if it helps at all.

```
 def test_untitled(self):
        sel = self.selenium
        sel.open("/Search/results.aspx")
        sel.click("_ctl0_Main_SearchRadio")
        sel.wait_for_page_to_load("30000")
        sel.type("-InputTextField", "ThinkCode")
        sel.click("_SearchMainUser")
        sel.wait_for_page_to_load("30000")
        try: self.failUnless(sel.is_text_present("ThinkCode"))
        except AssertionError, e: self.verificationErrors.append(str(e))
```

All I am trying to do is go to the resulting page that we are redirected to once we click the radio button. I read about javascript horrors in python web-scraping using urllib2. Hope a kind pythonista will help me soon :)

Comment: Why can't you use the `sel.click` method?

Comment: That is selenium just to trace the events. It is browser based if I am not wrong. My platform is a Linux box.

Comment: Your code looks good to me-- have you tried running it on a platform (even your local desktop machine) where you can watch the browser that Selenium is driving, so you can see exactly if your radio button is being clicked, your text field is being filled in, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to automate clicking the JavaScript button, which is difficult in Python, try monitoring what request is sent and then replicate this. There are various firefox extensions that will help you do this, such as [TamperData](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/), [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), and [LiveHttp](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/).